# Wi-Fi OS X & Android P2P

Tags: android, macos, wifi

I've been searching for a long time with no luck.

I'm trying to get a Mac OS X application to communicate with an Android application. Nothing more complicated than a chat client type application where text is typed in Android and sent to OS X (maybe via Cocoa or even a Java app).

I'm lost how to accomplish a Wi-Fi based communication between the two. I looked into Bluetooth first, but it seemed way over my head on the OS X side. Wi-Fi I assumed would be easier to implement.

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want your android to communicate with your Mac , there are many ways to do it.

1- With Internet- Queueing mechanism/DB mechanism
Your android could connect to SQS @AWS and write messages to the queue. You could write code in any language on OS X that reads off the queue and returns the string
Similar implementation can be done with a database- think orchestrate.io

2-Without internet
Assuming you've setup an ad-hoc connection between your mac and your android. You could simply open a socket and send and receive data on them. It's pretty straight-forward. Your Mac will run a TCP client and show the stream and print data out as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't know about TCP sockets. I got a quick test app together and got them to talk. Its exactly what I needed.  Thanks again.